# HTML5 website accent colors

Tags: css, html, sass

I am messing around with an HTML5 template for a small project and I am trying to change some colors in the template. Here is the template I am using: http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/landed/ The colors are defined in a .scss file called _vars.scss like this:

```
// Palette.
$palette: (
    accent1:            #f4793e,
    accent2:            #272833
);
```

The colors are then called out on a file called main.scss. I tried changing the hex code of the color but that didn't work. I also tried adding new lines of code such as accent3: XXXXXX and replacing this in the main.scss but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to do this? I am new to all this so I apologize if my question is not clear or if I am not giving you enough information. Thank in advance.

Comment: Look for the file here linked at the top of the page.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">`

Answer (score 0):

The styles you need to edit will be found in a file that ends in .css, not .scss.

Find that file, and modify the appropriate colors.